# Eloquent Subquery

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between a **student table** and a **apparatus table** (A student performs on many apparatuses and an apparatus has many students). I have a **student_results table** that has a composite primary key (**student_id** and **apparatus_id**) and a 3rd field called results).

I have written a query to find all the apparatuses that a student **DOES NOT** have a result. The example I give is for student with id = 121. 
The sub-query is.

```
SELECT apparatus_id, strapparatus_name FROM apparatuss 
WHERE apparatus_id <> ALL(SELECT apparatus_id FROM student_results 
WHERE student_id =' . 121 . ')';
```

I would like to write this using Eloquent (Laravel 4.1).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you already have your Eloquent models `Apparatus` and `StudentResult` set, this is a way:

```
Apparatus::whereNotIn(
    'apparatus_id',
    StudentResult::where('student_id', 121)->lists('apparatus_id')
)->get('apparatus_id', 'strapparatus_name');
```

Or, if you don't have a model for your student_results table, you can just:

```
Apparatus::whereNotIn(
    'apparatus_id',
    DB::table('student_results')->where('student_id', 121)->lists('apparatus_id'); 
)->get(array('apparatus_id', 'strapparatus_name'));
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for your response Antonio.I do have an **Apparatus** Model, but I am using a Pivot table for the **student_results**, thus I do not have a Model for **student_results**. Below is my solution.  I placed this in the route.php file to test the code before implementation.      $results2 = DB::table('student_results')->where('student_id', 121)->lists('apparatus_id');
$results = Apparatus::whereNotIn('apparatus_id', $results2)->get();
foreach($results as $tempresult){
        print '<li>' . $tempresult->apparatus_id . ' ' . $tempresult->strapparatus_name;
   }

Comment: Thank Antonio.  

I try that EXACT code.  Thanks. 

There is an issue this the ->get('apparatus_id', 'strapparatus_name');.  

So I had to simply make it  ->get();  

Error message was: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given.

Thanks again

PS no ";" at the end of  lists('apparatus_id')  <----------

Comment: Changing it to array should make it work as is. And there is no ";" there, it's the second parameter of whereNotIn.

Comment: You know what, @AntonioCarlosRibeiro? Turns out that, in my case, when I just wanted to get only the IDs from a Model by using `->get('id');` in order to apply an `->update([array])` into another model by using `->whereIn($ids)`, I got the error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given`. So I changed `get()` for `lists()` and now it is working! ☺ .... But Why?